# Create a Task on TFS With Backdated/History Date

Tags: tfs

The problem is i want to create a task on my TFS with backdated dates
I didn't find anything on internet Kindly suggest me a way either from GUI or APIs

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/Work%2520Items/Create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0#examples) with the **bypassRules** parameter to set the created date to whatever date you need.

`bypassRules` : Do not enforce the work item type rules on this update

```
POST https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?bypassRules=true&api-version=5.0
```

Sample request body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.CreatedDate",
    "value": "2020-06-05T02:28:18.603Z"
  }
]
```

Test in Postman:

[image]